# How to process TFL news feeds?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone suggest an idea of accessing tfl traffic news feeds?. The following is the link to get the url for the data feed.
http://www.tfl.gov.uk/businessandpartners/syndication/16492.aspx

The code I tried is as follows:

Code Sample:

```
$jq.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/businessandpartners/syndication/feed.aspx?email=***********@****.com&feedId=13',
    dataType: "xml",
    async: "false",
    success: function(xml) {
        $jq(xml).find('rr_event').each(function() {
            //var title=$jq(this).find('title').text();
            alert("success!");
        });
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the link requires you to have valid credentials to access what I expect to be some sort of xml feed? Also, if you are trying to access this url from a different domain other than www.tfl.gov.uk, you will need to use JSONP to fetch the data otherwise you will run  into a security exception (cross-domain error).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if I change the dataType in my jquery.ajax to jsonp will it work

Comment: I am getting the following errors:                                        Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/businessandpartners/syndication/feed.aspx?email=bensharonrose@gmail.com&feedId=13&callback=jQuery18104319907892495394_1348612225187&_=1348612225204". jquery-1.8.1.js:8169
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < feed.aspx:1